How to retrieve the current URL from a WebView in Flutter for the web platform?
I'm working on a Flutter app for the web, and I need to retrieve the current URL from a WebView. Specifically, I want to get the URL of the page that is being displayed in the WebView at any given time.
Is there a way to achieve this for the web platform in Flutter? I would appreciate any insights or recommendations on how to retrieve the current URL from a WebView, including any methods or techniques that might be helpful.
I tried several packages like webview_flutter_web: ^0.2.3+4 and easy_web_view: ^2.1.0, none of them seem to meet my requirements.

To retrieve the current URL from a WebView in Flutter for the web platform, you can use the webviewx package, which provides more flexibility for web-based applications.
solution
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webviewx/webviewx.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: WebViewExample(),
    );
  }
}

class WebViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WebViewExampleState createState() => _WebViewExampleState();
}

class _WebViewExampleState extends State<WebViewExample> {
  late WebViewXController webviewController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("WebView URL Example"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
            onPressed: () async {
              // Retrieve the current URL
              final currentUrl = await webviewController.currentUrl;
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(content: Text("Current URL: $currentUrl")),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: WebViewX(
        initialContent: 'https://flutter.dev',
        initialSourceType: SourceType.url,
        onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
          webviewController = controller;
        },
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      ),
    );
  }
}

Just as simple as
final currentUrl = await webviewController.currentUrl;


Thank you for the response! However, I’m unable to access the currentUrl property as it seems the WebViewController does not have such a property. Could you clarify or suggest an alternative approach?

import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart;late WebViewController _controller;final currentUrl = await _controller.currentUrl() actually reply does not support white space 3 different lines are there for other approch

You can checkout webview_flutter 4.10.0 which is recommended by flutter here.
Using -
onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
    if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
      return NavigationDecision.prevent;
    }
    return NavigationDecision.navigate;
  },

You can extract the url of the page, user is visiting.

Thank you for the response! However, the WebView Flutter package does not support the web platform. Could you suggest an alternative solution for web?

Apologies i didn't mention is that webview_flutter_web with webview_flutter allows you to use all the methods in web as per the documentation here
